# What was the intent for making Rem sacrifice herself for Misa?

Tags: death-note

We know Light is clever and smart and almost devilish? But I don't understand why Light wanted Rem out of the way?

What was his motive and what would have happened if it went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rem wanted to protect Misa and would kill Light if he let/caused Misa to die. Misa, however, was a good tool for Light and he could not kill her without raising suspicion towards himself.

Light also wanted L to die, but he could not kill him without knowing his real name. Rem could see everyone's name with her shinigami eyes, but would not kill anyone unless Misa was in trouble. So, Light put Misa in trouble and pressured Rem into killing L and Wastabi. As a result, Rem died and Light thought he had no more people in his way.

If Rem didn't kill L and Wastabi, Misa definitely would have been caught again and killed. There would have been a lot of suspicion towards Light, but he may have been able to talk himself out of it. If he did not, he would have died also. It was a gamble.

Answer (score 4):

Because Rem threatened to kill him should anything happen to Misa Misa. If he planned to use Misa Misa as a tool and perhaps sacrifice her eventually. He would have to get Rem out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

Misa Misa  was a useful tool but, with Rem always wanting to protect her and began to really care for her Light couldn't use her in anyway that would put her endanger for Rem would kill him the first chance she got. In order to use Misa and kill L he got Misa taken in and "endanger" putting the blame on L that he had done it. Doing that and edging Rem to kill him in order to save Misa since she was the only creature that could see L's real name doing this was killing to birds with one stone that kept getting in the way of Light's "good work."

Answer (score -1):

What could've happened if it went wrong:

Rem betrays Light to save Misa:

See this genius answer: [Why did Rem kill L?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19123/why-did-rem-kill-l/21151#21151)

Rem can talk to L and give L 2 options:

> Option 1 (what she partially did): I kill you, Watari and the whole task force and you'll never catch Kira nor Misa, failing in every aspect of your investigation.

> Option 2 (what she could have done before going for Option 1): I tell him that I can see who's the first Kira, and that the second Kira is Misa. But that as a Shinigami who's involved with Misa, I will not let anything happen to her, so I can either kill them all, or give them, in exchange for Misa's innocence), the name for the first Kira. If they refuse this deal, then they will have none (and go to Option 1).

Comment: She obviously couldn't do that because that will harm Misa either way lol, telling L Misa is the 2nd kira is the last thing could go wrong. And except for that I cannot see how you answered the question.